# Parsing XML using lxml, unable to get text when there is another child node

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, lxml

I am parsing a XML file, downloaded from internet, using `lxml`. It has a structure something similar to this:

```
<root>
    <a>Some text in A node</a>
    <b><c>Some text in C node</c>Some text in B node</b>
</root>
```

I want to print the text inside the nodes with the following piece of code:

```
from lxml import etree
doc = etree.parse('some.xml')
root = doc.getroot()
for ch in root:
    print ch.text
```

**Output**

```
Some text in A node
None
```

This is not printing the `text` for `<B>`. Why? When I change the XML (shown below), `text` first and then child nodes, I get the correct output. Is it something to do with the XML syntax or `lxml`? Since I cannot control the XML because it is directly downloaded from the internet, I need a way to get the text as it is in the previous format.

```
<root>
    <a>Some text in A node</a>
    <b>Some text in B node<c>Some text in C node</c></b>
</root>
```

**Output**

```
Some text in A node
Some text in B node
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [`lxml.etree._Element` documentation](http://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._Element-class.html):

`text` property returns a text before the first subelement. This is either a string or the value None, if there was no text.

To print any first text in the tag, try following which use xpath to get child text node:

```
for ch in root:
    print next((x for x in ch.xpath('text()')), None)
```

or:

```
for ch in root.xpath('/text()'):
    print ch
```

Comment: Yes true, the documentation says it. Using `xpath()` gets the text no matter where it is placed. Thanks.